# Can't connect Wi-Fi on Linux Mint 14

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, linux-mint

I have got Linux Mint 14 and everything worked fine until today. Today I installed and configured a new router I bought recently, then I tried to connect it. I clicked on the router name in the list in the bottom right corner, but nothing happened. I can see all the routers around, but as I click on any of them in the list, nothing happens. As I mentioned, it doesn't depend on router. System doesn't show that it tries to connect the router, otherwise there would a bold dot near router name appear.

And as I said, it worked earlier. I didn't make any notable manipulations on system last time, so I can't give any other advice.

Some information on my system:

```
CPU:       Dual core Pentium CPU T4300 (-MCP-) clocked at 1200.00 MHz 
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY driver: wl 
           IF: eth1 state: dormant mac: 00:26:82:3c:29:99
           Card-2: Broadcom NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express driver: tg3 
           IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 00:26:22:d7:83:7b

Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try connecting [using iwconfig](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/354).